# Can't Access Value Of Array Posted via Post Method in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have create a array of user information and post it to another page for using.. but when i access it its not return any value.. only return A or r..

Can Any Buddy Help Me..

Create Array

```
  <?php 
    $datas= array(
    "Scountry"=>'ZA',
    "SName"=>$SName,
    "SCompany"=>$SCompany,
    "SAddress"=>$SAddress,
     "SAddress2"=>$SAddress2,
    "SAddress3"=>$SAddress3,
    "ssPlace"=>$fr[0],
    "sZip"=>$fr[1],
    "SPhone"=>$SPhone,
    "SMobile"=>$SMobile,
    "SEmail"=>$SEmail,
    "SFex"=>$SFex       
    );
    ?>
```

My Post Form Is

```
    <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="submit" name="submit">
   <input type="hidden" name="clientdata" id="clientdata" value="<?php print_r($datas); ?>">

   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
```

And My Access Code of submit.php

```
     <?php 
     $clientdata = $_POST['clientdata'];
    print_r($clientdata);
      ?>
```

when i print it with print

```
      print_r($clientdata);
```

following result show

```
       Array ( [Scountry] => ZA [SName] => name [SCompany] => adfsd [SAddress] => asdf [SAddress2] => adsf [SAddress3] => asdf [ssPlace] => adfddfd [sZip] => 0037 [SPhone] => 222222222 [SMobile] => 9926036842 [SEmail] => abc@gmail.com [SFex] => 1111111111)
```

My Problem Is When I access Particular Value of array attribute its not print...

```
    echo $clientdata->Scountry;
```

No Result Show

when i use

```
    echo $clientdata[Scountry];
```

No Result Show

Can Any Body Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a string as a key for an array. The key has to be between `"`, otherwise php will think you are looking for a constant.

```
echo $clientdata["Scountry"];
```

**update:**

You cannot just print_r data as a value from an input field, you will have to serialize it. this creates a json string from the array.

```
<input type="hidden" name="clientdata" id="clientdata" value="<?php echo json_encode($datas); ?>">
```

Now, in your code, you can just decode this json string to an object:

```
$clientdata = json_decode($_POST['clientdata']);
echo $clientdata->Scountry;
```

Comment: $clientdata = json_decode($_POST['clientdata']);
echo $clientdata->Scountry;

Comment: <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="submit" name="submit">

<input type="hidden" name="clientdata" id="clientdata" value="<?php json_encode($datas); ?>"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>

Comment: My bad, you need to echo the data, `<?php echo json_encode($datas); ?>`.

Comment: we need to add any class for json

Answer (score 0):

Implode your array and post it from the Form.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="submit" name="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientdata" id="clientdata" value="<?php implode('@@#@@',$datas); ?>"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And on your PHP File:

```
<?php 
$clientdata = $_POST['clientdata'];
$clientArray = explode('@@#@@',$clientdata);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($clientArray);

echo $clientArray['Secondary'];
?>
```